# VBA with MailEnvelope stopped working

Tags: vba, excel

Could you please advise me on the following problem.

I have got an excel workbook with VBA which when run should email a dashboard to the email recipients in a list.

Now the macro stopped working. Or rather the macro starts to work, but does not generate the email:
When run, it asks if an email should be sent, but when "yes" is selected nothing happens?!
I was able run older version of the workbook and its macro. As the macro is working with active worksheet it executed the macro and sent the email with the current dashboard.
However when I pasted the code in to the current workbook it doest execute fully. An email is not generated.
Therefore it seems like something has been disabled withing the current workbook.
A colleague did some changes in the dashboard - added rows and columns and then adjusted the range in VBA. Otherwise I am not aware of any other changes.

Thank you in advance.

Please see below the code:

```
'Send Bulk Email From Excel Using VBA Code
Sub SendDailyReport()
    'Below Loop can be changed to While Loop or increase the limit (10) if your list has more than 10 mail ids
    Dim SendTo As String
    Dim ToMSg As String
 If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to send this report?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    For I = 2 To 1000
        SendTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(I, 1)
        If SendTo <> ñî Then
            ToMSg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(I, 2)
            Send_Range SendTo, ToMSg
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
Sub Send_Range(SendTo As String, ToMSg As String)


   ' Select the range of cells on the active worksheet.
   ActiveSheet.Range("F4:S46").Select

   ' Show the envelope on the ActiveWorkbook.
   ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

   ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
   ' some header text to the email body. It also sets
   ' the To and Subject lines. Finally the message
   ' is sent.
   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = ""
      .Item.To = SendTo
      .Item.Subject = ToMSg
      .Item.Send
   End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Change ".Item.Send" to ".Item.Display". Does this show you an email body?

Comment: What is the value of this fancy named variable - `ñî`? Is it declared?

Comment: @underbot, I changed to "Item.Display", but it didnt change anything. However some progress as per the next comment.. Thank you.

Comment: @Vityata thank you for the tip. I though that it means "" - empty. I did replace it with "end" just to try and actually the MailEnvelope loaded in the Excel. I then I received this error: "Run-time error 1004. Select method of Range class failed. When I select Debug, the problem seems to be the range/VBA line: ActiveSheet.Range("F4:S46").Select

Comment: @Vityata In the subject of the EmailEnvelope is actually text from a cell which is on a different sheet!
I actually tried this few times and run the VBA with the error. At one try I have received loads of emails from this code with the correct dashboard, but subject taken from cells in another sheet. Any idea on this please?

Comment: @Miroslav - the subject is `ToMSg` taken from here: `ToMSg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(I, 2)`. Thus, it is taken from the first sheet of the workbook, not the `ActiveSheet`. Change simply delete `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` and it should work.

Comment: @Vityata Thank you very much. This worked! I never realised that the Sheets(1) relates to the sheets order instead to the name. Thank you again.

Comment: @Miroslav - I am afraid to ask what is the name of the sheet now...

Answer (score 0):

The subject of `ToMSg` is taken from here:

```
ToMSg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(I, 2)
```

Thus, it is taken from the first sheet of the workbook, not the `ActiveSheet`.

Delete `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` and it should work.